Way to update exitsting row from db sqlalchemy orm
Is there function updates data from db ex:
user = User()
user.name = 'Jonh'

session.add(user)
session.commit()

session.foo(user)

print(user.id) # now we have id of user


ps: i am looking for foo() function
i tried to use google and search in documentation but i didn't find solution

No, unfortunately, there's not any existing method for the aim you want to achieve. But you can achieve the same aim through updating the object "user" with its identity (ID):
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///users_database.db')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

user = User(name='John')
session.add(user)
session.commit()

session.refresh(user)

print(user.id)

You can use the built-in refresh() method in order to reload the object state from the database you're working on.
